# Shared hosting on IIS7. Not able to access resources with 'StaticFileModule' handlers

Tags: iis, iis-7

I have directories for images and styles, with a `Web.config` file (using Orchard). In that `Web.config` there is a line causing a problem on my shared hosting (running fine in WebMatrix):

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Script,Read">
      <!--
      iis7 - for any request to a file exists on disk, return it via native http module.
      accessPolicy 'Script' is to allow for a managed 404 page.
      -->
      <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

When I try to access any files from that directory I get a 500 page:

> 500 - Internal server error.
>   There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

When I delete the line

```
<add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
```

it displays the resources.

How can I fix this problem without altering the `Web.config` file located in each directory containing files which are intended to be accessed directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you can (on Shared hosting, I mean).

The error **clearly** says: *"Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'StaticFile"*. This means that there is already an entry with `name="StaticFile"` somewhere above in config hierarchy (in another web.config in a parent folder .. or, most likely, global web server config.

**To solve it, you have to remove existing config line first.** You have to add `<remove name="StaticFile" />` line into your `<handlers>` section before adding your own handler, for example:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Script,Read">
        <remove name="StaticFile" />
        <!--
        iis7 - for any request to a file exists on disk, return it via native http module.
        accessPolicy 'Script' is to allow for a managed 404 page.
        -->
        <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

If you would have full control over your server (which you do not, since you are on shared hosting) you could remove `StaticFile` handler from global IIS config ... but is it wise?? Adding the `<remove...>` line is a correct approach for both scenarios.

Comment: Yep - that, or <clear /> the collection first at the web.config level, and then be explicit about every single handler you need enabled.

Comment: That Might have been the problem. I didn't have the possibility to test it, however I think this would work in certain cases. I re-created the website, exactly as I did the first time, but this time it worked. Strange. However thank you for your answer, it will be helpful for many others who encounter similar problems.